# Windows Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange Deriving key

Tags: windows, winapi, encryption, cryptography, aes

So I am interacting between OpenSSL and the BCrypt functions on windows. I am writing an app in QT and can only use BCrypt for client side and OpenSSL on the server side. I have successfully done a DH key exchange the only issue I am having is how would I manage to derive a AES 128 key from a shared secret. The code I am using for the AES 128 encryption is https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/Security/CipherEncryptionDecryption/cpp/CipherEncryptionDecryption.cpp where I pass the spassword as sha1 of the shared secret.

the code on the PHP server side that I am using is:

```
echo bin2hex(openssl_pbkdf2(sha1($shared_secret), $salt, $keylen, $iterations, 'sha256'));
```

The iterations, salt, and everything matches on the client & server side. However the results do not match. What is the reason for this?

Comment: What type is `$shared_secret`? If it is a string make sure that you use the same charset for String-> byte[] conversion before hashing it.

Comment: $shared_secret is returned from openssl_dh_compute_key and is binary. The input is string and it matches the result of the client. That is not the issue. The issue is with using the KDF.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing sha1 and sha256:

```
...sha1($shared_secret)...'sha256'...
```

Comment: No. I am using SHA256 for the KDF. For the password I am taking the SHA1 of the shared secret.